# Players who won at least 2 world cups?

Tags: football

I know of a few players who won at least 2 world cups, 
Pele, Garrincha, Didi, Vava, Giusseppe Meassa, Daniel Passarella, Ronaldo

are there more?

Comment: The World Cup has been won twice in a row on two occasions: by Italy (1934, 1938) and Brazil (1958, 1962). If check out players from those squads you might find some more double winners.

Comment: yes, but you have to add players like Passarella (1978-1986) or Ronaldo (1994-2002)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There have been 21 [players who have won multiple FIFA World Cups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_players_who_have_won_multiple_FIFA_World_Cups):

- Pelé – 1958, 1962, 1970
- Cafu – 1994, 2002
- Hilderaldo Bellini – 1958, 1962
- Carlos José Castilho – 1958, 1962
- Didi – 1958, 1962
- Djalma Santos – 1958, 1962
- Garrincha – 1958, 1962
- Gilmar – 1958, 1962
- Mauro – 1958, 1962
- Nílton Santos – 1958, 1962
- Pepe – 1958, 1962
- Vavá – 1958, 1962
- Mário Zagallo – 1958, 1962
- Zito – 1958, 1962
- Zózimo – 1958, 1962
- Ronaldo – 1994, 2002
- Giovanni Ferrari – 1934, 1938
- Guido Masetti – 1934, 1938
- Giuseppe Meazza – 1934, 1938
- Eraldo Monzeglio – 1934, 1938
- Daniel Passarella – 1978, 1986

Comment: But note that five players (Bellini, Mauro, Zózimo, Ronaldo, Passarella) ended up as unused players in one of the tournaments, and three others (Castilho, Pepe, Masetti) were unused players in both. If we want to take these factors into account (e.g., UEFA doesn't award Champions League medals to unused players of the winning club), we end up with 13 multiple winners.